# Как увеличить страницу html?

Tags: html, html5, веб-сайт

У меня есть html-страница, но все на ней маленькое. Как можно увеличить и центрировать все объекты? Заранее спасибо.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <body>
   <div class = "container">
      <style>

         p {
         min-width: 3200px;
         color: blue;

         }

      </style>

      <p>I hope you are satisfied with the service  ;)

      <p>

         <!-- GFG is the name of the 

            file to be downloaded-->

         <!-- In order to run the code, 

            the location of the file 

            "dnn.zip" needs to 

            be changed to your local directory,

            both the HTML and downloadable file 

            needs to be present in the same directory -->

         <p><a href="https://upnow-prod.ff45e40d1a1c8f7e7de4e976d0c9e555.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/vRxHCBLc32cTsqYbK1xfhOwuYSE3/a54eca7f-c137-47ef-a23d-20419f704b76?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=cdd12e35bbd220303957dc5603a4cc8e%2F20231113%2Fauto%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231113T052846Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-Signature=b4066165bdcb788edc68e3d9b2c234fc463a99371e903e3df9e16a6bf9db0b12&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22dnn.zip%22" download="dnn"></p>

         <button type="button">Download</button>

         </a>
              <p><a href="https://national-above-aphid.ngrok-free.app/files/primary%3Ahttpfiles/dnn.zip" download="dnn"></p>

         <button type="button">Download (localhost)</button>

         </a>
              <p><a href="http://file-st14.karelia.ru/v7qvg8/c1a195380ba528f13fb7f74af6b4c3aa/dd96ae5bae7f1e7d255acfecfca9ca1d/dnn.zip" </p>

         <button type="button">Download Mirror (file.karelia)</button>

         </a>
         <p><a href="http://download943.mediafire.com/e24irtpakicgD5G1pnMQKVC12cej2HEKQhxNc3KyUDcJ4kyLh-U-pS5yLjO6tzt5U22MgPFCVQ-GftC2o9z_wOokfqndJD6HgP5yHpibzjW92msb8u7fhM0PBuNbPLkyfTn0BkkNRsuBpUaCx-IPsGkfkS2KkQzG2gv9PM15Q1ah/k2lqu8nuekzeavd/dnn.zip?force" target="_blank"</p>

         <button type="button">Download Mirror (mediafire)</button>

         </a>
         <p><a href="old"</p>

         <button type="button">Old site</button>

         </a>
         <p><a href="chrome-native://newtab"</p>

         <button type="button">Fast newtab</button>

         </a>
         <p><a href="google-hacking-database"</p>

         <button type="button">google db exploit</button>

         </a>
         <p><a href="freecpvideo"</p>

         <button type="button">free cp video</button>

         </a>
         
   </body>
   </div>

</html>
```

Если что на последней кнопке рикролл, не надо меня сватать :).

Comment: Мой совет: воспользуйтесь CSS-стилями. Я вижу, Вы в тэге ```<style>``` уже начали их прописывать для параграфа ```p```. Задайте ```font-size``` для размера шрифта, ```text-align``` для выравнивания и т.д. - в зависимости от того результата, который желаете получить

Comment: @Stark спасибо за ответ, текст у меня получалось увеличить, отдельно объекты тоже, но дело в том, что при увеличении все ломается, текст в кнопках съезжает и т.д., ищу способ сразу всю страницу разом и пропорционально увеличить.

Comment: Всё равно не очень понятно. Во-первых, зачем Вы указываете минимальную ширину параграфа 3200px: на подавляющем числе мониторов он будет давать горизонтальный скролл для всей страницы  и всё Ваше выравнивание будет производится не относительно экрана, а относительно общей ширины страницы.... Во-вторых, у Вас есть оборачивающий тэг ```<div class = "container">``` - чтобы центрировать все элементы, обратитесь к нему и укажите: ```text-align: center;```. Для увеличения всех элементов на странице, обратитесь ко всем дочерним элементам этого же div'а: ```.container * {...}```

Comment: вам бы для начала синтаксические ошибки поправить... `</body></div></html>`...`<a href="chrome-native://newtab"</p>` а потом уже можно и на масштабирование смотреть. а вообще можно покрутить колёсико при зажатом `CTRL` в качестве дэмо версии желаемого :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, у вас проблемы из-за того, что браузер пытается "впихнуть" ваши 3200 ширины в ваш монитор. Через `scale` вы увеличиваете масштаб деталей. Думаю, это не самое лучшее решение. Попробуйте добавить

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

```
<html lang="ru">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    *****new*****
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    *************
    и т.д.
```

Не все устройства одинаковые по ширине, поэтому вы должны масштабировать ваш сайт в зависимости от размера устройства, на котором этот сайт открывается.
`width=device-width` - строчка, которая фактически обозначает, что размер области просмотра равен размеру экрана устройства.
`initial-scale=1.0` - Уровень масштабирования при загрузке страницы. `0.1` - минимум, `10` - максимум. `1` - дефолт

Comment: Сначала подумал, что разница нет, а как оказалось у меня стран цу в сторону двигать можно,  ваш ответ лучше, спасибо.

Comment: Можно вопрос? У меня такая проблема: когда я открываю html в эмуляторе (например trebedit), то initial-scale отлично работает, при изменении значения все работает как надо, но в браузерах при изменении значения ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Zailox вы проверьте ваш код на наличие ошибок через валидатор. Возможно, где-то не закрыли тег.   Проверить можно тут - https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы, вот решение, которое мне помогло:

````
<div class = "container" style="text-align: center"> ```<= спасибо @Stark за помощь, с помощью style=... добавлено центрирование```

...

p {
         scale: 3 ```<= добавил scale```;
         color: blue;
         margin: 100px; ```<= добавил margin для сохранения расстояния между блоками```

         }

...

download="dnn">```<= не понимал, почему первые 2 кнопки не увеличиваются, нужно убрать этот '>' и все будет хорошо```</p>
````

Вроде все, теперь сайт выглядит куда лучше.
[image: Вот конечный результат]